Unable to delete the Promo code, unable to update attribute max dedemption
Is there a limitation that we can not update the attributes other than active and metadata properties once the Promo codes are created?
Also, I am unable to delete the promo code; the only option is to delete the coupon, which will delete all promo codes.
I have observed that there are few products available that have integration with Stripe but they support Editing and deleting the Coupn and Promo codes.
In my case, I am using Stripe's connected Account in Standard Mode.

Yes it's correct that you can only change a limited properties of Promotion Code. You can change the minimum_amount too through, but not any other properties like max_redemptions etc...
Promotion Code could already be used when you want to upodate it, which would leads to unexpected behavior if the other properties is editable. The other products may just set its Promotion Code to inactive and recreate a new one.
